# Error in getting Information about current user in Titanium for ios

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I've developed an application which have a screen to Login to the application.I need to display the details of the current user in main page.It works well when I logging into the app at first time. But i'm getting an error : **You need to sign in or sign up before continuing** when i try to sign in again after logout. There is no issue in android os with same code

Here is a sample code,

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : '#520000'
});

var btnLogin = Ti.UI.createButton({

    title   : 'Login',
    top     : '20%',
    width   : '50%'
});
var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');

win.add(btnLogin);
win.open();

btnLogin.addEventListener('click', Login);

function Login(){

    Cloud.Users.login({
        login: 'anand@gmail.com',
        password: 'anandt'
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            var user = e.users[0];  
            var mainWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
                backgroundColor : '#005200',
                url             : 'logout.js'
            });

            mainWin.open();

        } else {
            alert('Error: ' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
});
}
```

Main page of application

```
var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');

var logoutWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var btnLogout = Ti.UI.createButton({    
    title   : 'Logout',
    top     : '20%',
    width   : '50%'
});

logoutWin.add(btnLogout);
logoutWin.addEventListener('open', function(){
    Cloud.Users.showMe(function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            var user = e.users[0];
            alert('user is ' + 'first name: ' + user.first_name + ' ' + 'last name: ' + user.last_name);
        } else {
            alert('Error: ' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
});
btnLogout.addEventListener('click', Logout);


function Logout()
{
    Cloud.Users.logout(function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            logoutWin.close();
        } else {
            alert('Error: ' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
}
```

This is the screen showing after the user logged in for the first time without any logout

[image: This is the screen showing after the user logged in for the first time without any logout]

This is the screen showing after the user logged in with one or more logout(without restarting the app)
[image: This is the screen showing after the user logged in with one or more logout(without restarting the app)]

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading up the window with a URL is causing the session ID to get mangled between the contexts. Don't use URLs.

Comment: Thank you Dawson for your reply. But in my application, I have to call login and logout fromdifferent files. Can you suggest any alternatives for URLs

Comment: Big picture, you should work to structure your apps with CommonJS modules http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/12/commonjs-module-guide-for-1-8.html Rather than Ti.UI.createWindow({ url: 'blah.js' }).open(), require('blah').createWindow().open();